# Format data in R for specific tables

Tags: r, formatting

I'm new to R and need some help in formatting some data. I have 4 tables. The first one (Image_pos) contains the image_number along with its X and Y co-ords. Second one (Learning) contains the same image_number along with X and Y co-ordinates of where it was placed during a Learning Phase. (Note that the same image occurs multiple times during a learning phase) Third one ( Testing) again contains the same image_number along with X and Y co-ordinates of where it was placed during a Testing Phase. (Each image just occurs once) So, I want to format all this data into one table with the following columns. Image_no, Actual_X, Actual_Y, Placed_x, Placed_Y, Error, Phase(Learning/Testing). I would want to write an R script which could do this Any help would be appreciated

Here is a snippet of the data (Actual_X, Actual_Y, Placed_X, Placed_Y, Phase, Error) (22.1 22.1 33.1 55.6 35.25, Learning) (22.1, 22.1, 19, 33.6, 11.91, Learning) (22.1, 22.1, 22.3, 24.5, 2.4 Testing)

Comment: I don't understand your first data row.  It seems to have an extra column?

Comment: Does it make sense now?

Comment: How about the same change in the second paragraph?  I see that 35.25 is the euclidean distance between (22.1, 22.1) and (33.1,55.6) whereas the other two rows have no explicit error, however the Phase and Error headers are switched?  It would be great material for a table, but alas http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/73566/is-there-markdown-to-create-tables

Comment: I'm sorry, while copying the data. I forgot about the error for the last two rows. My main issue is how do I aggregate the data from different tables and group them together using a certain measure